# Angular && condition doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I use following code snip.

```
 <div data-ng-class="{ sel_style : $index!=0 && {{selClaz.row[$index].colorId }}  == {{selClaz.row[$index-1].colorId }} }" >
```

Here what is done is, a CSS style is assigned to a `div` based on a condition. Also, 'selClaz.row' is iterated and if the current object's colorId value is equal to previous object, then the final boolean expression should be true.  But this should not be executed for first iteration which is `$index==0` . Therefore, a condition to avoid execution for first index, `$index !=0` is added.  But exception is thrown mentioning above line has syntax error. console further shows `&amp;&amp;` for above `&&`  . So how can I fix this ?  I use angular 1.3

Comment: You sure && is the problem and not {{ }}?

Answer (score 3):

Couple things wrong with your `ng-class`

-You need to wrap your class in quotes, due to the `_`

-You dont need `{{}}` in `ng-class` directive

```
data-ng-class="{ 'sel_style' : $index!=0 && selClaz.row[$index].colorId == selClaz.row[$index-1].colorId }"
```